# Theoretical time complexity calculation of nested dependent for loops

Tags: time-complexity, language-agnostic, big-o, nested-loops, complexity-theory

How do I calculate the big-O time complexity of the following nested *for* loop with dependent indices:

```
void function1 (int n)
{
     int x = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i <= n/2; i+=3)
        for (int j = i; j <= n/4; j+=2)
           x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexity of the code is defined as how many times your code will be executed for a given `n`. 
There are two ways to do it.

1. Simulation: Run the code for different value of `n` and find out the values. In this case this is equivalent to the final value of `x`.
2. Theoretical:

Let's first check for each `i` how many times your code runs:

 Using the arithmetic progression formula (a_n = a_1 + (k-1)*d):

- `i=0` => `n/4 = 0 + (k-1)*2` => `n/8 + 1` times
- `i=3` => `n/4 = 3 + (k-1)*2` => `(n-12)/8 + 1` times
- `i=6` => `n/4 = 6 + (k-1)*2` => `(n-24)/8 + 1` times
- `i=9` => `n/4 = 9 + (k-1)*2` => `(n-36)/8 + 1` times

   
   Let's check the last `i's` now:
- `i=n/4` => `n/4 = n/4 + (k-1)*2` => `1` times
- `i=n/4 - 3` => `n/4 = (n/4-3) + (k-1)*2` => `3/2 + 1` times
- `i=n/4 - 6` => `n/4 = (n/4-6) + (k-1)*2` => `6/2 + 1` times

So total number of times inner loop will be running is:

```
= (1) + (3/2 + 1) + (6/2 + 1) + (9/2 + 1) ...  + ((n-12)/8 + 1)+ (n/8 + 1)
=> (0/2 + 1) + (3/2 + 1) + (6/2 + 1) + (9/2 + 1) ...  + ((n-12)/8 + 1)+ (n/8 + 1)
```

Can be written as:

```
=> (0/2 + 3/2 + 6/2 + ... (n-12)/8 + n/8) + (1 + 1 + 1 ... 1 + 1)
```

Let's assume there are total P terms in the series: 
Let's find out P:

```
n/8 = (0/2) + (P-1)*(3/2)   =>   P = (n+12)/12
```

Now summing up the above series:

```
= [(P/2) (0/2 + (P-1) * 3/2)] + [P]
= P(3P+1)/4
= (n+12)(3(n+12)+12)/(4*12*12)
= (n^2 + 28n + 96)/192
```

So the final complexity of the code is

```
= (number of operation in each iteration) * (n^2 + 28n + 96)/192
```

Now look at the term `(n^2 + 28n + 96)/192` For a very large `n` this will be close to `~n^2`

Following is the complexity comparison: 
Linear scale was difficult to analyse to I plotted log scale. Though for small `n` you don't see the complexity converging to n^2.

[image: complexityComparison]

Answer (score 0):

Using a very relax approach one can say that:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n/2; i+=3){
        for (int j = i; j <= n/4; j+=2) {
            x++;
        }
    }
```

in the same as :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n/4; i+=3){
    for (int j = i; j <= n/4; j+=2) {
        x++;
    }
}
```

since with i > n/4 the inner loop will not execute. Moreover, to simplify the math you can say that the code is approximately the same as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n/4; i+=3){
    for (int j = i; j < n/4; j+=2) {
        x++;
    }
}
```

since the context is `big-O` it does not make a difference for the calculation of the upper-bound of the double loop. The number of iterations of a loop of the form:

```
    for (int j = a; j < b; j += c)
```

can be calculated using the formula `(b - a) /c`. Hence, the inner loop will run approximately `((n/4) - i) / 2)` times, or n/8 - i/2 times.

The outer-loop can be thought as running from k=0 until n/12.  So with both loops we have

```
the summation of [k=0 to n/12] of (n/8 - 3k/2),
```

which is equivalent to

```
the summation [k=0 to n/12] of n/8  -  the summation [k=0 to n/12] of 3k/2.
```

Hence,

`(N^2) / 96  -  the summation [[k=0 to n/12] of 3k/2`

which is approximately `(n^2) / 192`. Therefore, the upper bound is `O (n^2)`.